# How can I loop through array and sum only half the items? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays

say I have an array of ten items, and I want to make 2 separate arrays which sums the items inside the original one by odd and even distribution.
For example:

```
OriginalArray [288,333,313,296,102,299,333,333,316,289]
arraySumA [288,288+313,288+313+102,288+313+102+333,288+313+102+333+316]
arraySumB [333,333+296,333+296+299,333+296+299+333,...]
```

how can I do that using no more than one loop (if possible)?

**Update:** thanks all of you guys for your suggestions, I didn't use them eventually but they've certainly helped me devise my own solution.
Especially thanks to you @Dana Woodman your use of push() function was "the missing piece in my puzzle" :)

Comment: BTW, in your example, some of your sums mix odd and even items (e.g. `333+296`), might trip up some people.

Comment: Perhaps I'm reading your question wrong, are you trying to sum items alternating between odd and even in each list?

Answer (score 2):

```
var arraySumA = OriginalArray.reduce(function(c, x, i) {
    if(i % 2==1) c += x;
    return c;
});

var arraySumB = OriginalArray.reduce(function(c, x, i) {
    if(i % 2==0) c += x;
    return c;
});
```

Or with one `Array.prototype.reduce` call:

```
var sums = OriginalArray.reduce(function(c, x, i) {
    if(i % 2==0) c.even += x;
    else c.odd += x;
    return c;
}, {even: 0, odd: 0});
```

Comment: but isn't this solution exactly two loops?

Comment: The second answer does not give him two arrays

Comment: It does give him two arrays...they just happen to be in an object.

Comment: It would be easy enough to say `var arrayA = sums.even;` etc.  You could even re-factor this example to use an array or object containing the two arrays in the external scope instead of a new object.  Saying that this answer isn't good because it doesn't "return two arrays" in the external scope is a lot like saying "that variable isn't named the way the OP wants".  SO's not about hand-holding, it's about solving problems.

Answer (score 1):

Use a for loop with a mod check for even or odd indices. Push the sum of the relevant array into the next value of the relevant array.

```
for(var i = 0; i < original.length; i++){
  if( i % 2 == 0 ){
    sumA.push(original[i]+(sumA[sumA.length-1]|0));
  }else{
    sumB.push(original[i]+(sumB[sumB.length-1]|0));
  }
}
```

Using the bitwise OR `|0` here ensures that an undefined value from sum[-1] is 0.

```js
var original = [288,333,313,296,102,299,333,333,316,289];
var sumA = [], sumB = [];

for(var i = 0; i < original.length; i++){
  if( i % 2 == 0 ){
    sumA.push(original[i]+(sumA[sumA.length-1]|0));
  }else{
    sumB.push(original[i]+(sumB[sumB.length-1]|0));
  }
}

$("#a").text(JSON.stringify(sumA));
$("#b").text(JSON.stringify(sumB));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you're looking for with only one loop:

```
var OriginalArray = [288,333,313,296,102,299,333,333,316,289];
var arraySumA = [];
var arraySumB = [];

// You use any type of iterator here, like a standard for-loop as well.    
OriginalArray.forEach(function (num) {
  if (num % 2 === 0) {
    // Sum of even items
    var prev = arraySumA[arraySumA.length - 1] | 0;
    arraySumA.push(prev + num);
  } else {
    // Sum of odd items
    var prev = arraySumB[arraySumB.length - 1] | 0;
    arraySumB.push(prev + num);
  }
});

/*
Results in:
arraySumA = [288, 584, 686, 1002]
arraySumB = [333, 646, 945, 1278, 1611, 1900]
*/
```

If the sum of the previous is the sum of the existing array then you should just have to add the previous item to the current one.

*Style note: it's generally considered bad practice to use [Pascal Case](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PascalCase) on variables unless they're classes*